# Спецификатор noexcept

Tags: c++, функции, исключения, c++11, объявление

```
class Math { 
    public: 
        static bool __fastcall      IsPowerOfTwo( int x ) noexcept;
};

__forceinline bool Math::IsPowerOfTwo( int x ) { // хз что делает :D
    return ( x & ( x - 1 ) ) == 0 && x > 0;
}
```

noexcept надо тоже писать в определении?

Comment: гугл лол не рулит :O

Comment: error C2382: Math::IsPowerOfTwo: переопределение; разные спецификации исключений

Comment: все закрыть тему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поясню про выражение

`x & (x-1) == 0 && x > 0`

оно проверяет положительное число `x` на степень двойки

тоесть это числа вида
`x = 2^i`, где `i` позиция единственного единичного бита

в двоичном представлении имеют следующий вид:

`0000...100000 = 2^i = x`

а числа `x - 1` имеют вид

`0000...011111 = 1*2^i-1 + 1*2^i-2 + ... + 1*2^0 = x-1`

тоесть все разряды начиная с `i-1` ого единичные,

отсюда если побитово применить `AND` тоесть `x & (x-1)` получим `0` что означает что, число `x` это степень двойки, в противном случае, соотвественно не является степенью двойки

Answer (score 8):

Согласно стандарту C++ (15.4 Exception speciﬁcation)

> 5 If any declaration of a function has an exception-speciﬁcation that
>   is not a noexcept-speciﬁcation allowing all exceptions, all
>   declarations, including the deﬁnition and any explicit specialization,
>   of that function shall have a compatible exception-speciﬁcation....

Это значит, что определение функции `IsPowerOfTwo` также должно содержать спецификацию исключения `noexcept` или `noexcept( true )`

Что касается самой функции, то она определяет, является ли заданное положительное целое число степенью 2.

( x & ( x - 1 ) ) == 0 && x > 0;

Выражение `( x & ( x - 1 ) )` означает следующее. Все целые числа, являющиеся степенью 2 имеют следующий вид (на примере одного байта)

```
0000 0001
0000 0010
0000 0100
0000 1000
0001 0000
0010 0000
0100 0000
```

и т.д. для остальных байтов. То есть в числе присутствует лишь одна битовая 1. Если для какого-нибудь из перечисленных чисел вычесть 1, то получим

```
   0000 0100 - 1 == 0000 0011
```

Теперь если сделать битовую операцию & (AND) с полученными числами, то результат будет равен 0.

```
   0000 0100
   0000 0011
   =========
   0000 0000
```

Если бы исходное число не являлось степенью 2, как, например,

```
   0000 1100
```

то есть если оно содержит более одной битовой 1, то после вычитания 1 в старших разрядах сохранятся другие единицы, если они присутствуют в числе

```
   0000 1100 - 1 == 0000 1011
        ^                ^
```

Поэтому побитовая операция & (AND) не даст 0.

```
   0000 1100
   0000 1011
   =========
   0000 1000
```