# Проверить является ли число степенью двойки

Tags: c++

где проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int numb{2};
  int ToPower ;

  cout << "Enter number : ";
  cin >> ToPower;

  for (int i = 1; i<=5; i++)
  {

   if (numb^i == ToPower)
   {
    cout << "Number" << ToPower<<" is power of 2" << endl;   
   }
   else
   {

   cout << "Number isn*t power of two" << endl;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Лучше использовать unsigned, иначе ещё придётся обрабатывать минимальное отрицательное число, которое не является степенью двойки..

Comment: [`std::has_single_bit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/has_single_bit)

Answer (score 12):

Проблема в том, что операция `^` в C++ (и многих других языках) означает не возведение в степень, а [побитное исключающее или](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3akey979.aspx).

Для возведения *двойки* в неотрицательную степень `k` проще всего использовать просто

```
1 << k
```

---

А для проверки того, является ли число `v` степенью двойки, есть [знаменитый трюк](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2):

```
bool isPowerOfTwo = v && !(v & (v - 1));
```

Если вы знакомы с двоичной системой, вам доставит удовольствие разбирать, почему именно он работает.

Comment: а если компилятор поддерживает встроенные функции... для степени двойки код Хэмминга(popcount, число ненулевых бит) равен 1. Многие процессоры имеют это как одну инструкцию.

Comment: @Swift: В стандарте C++ popcount, если я не ошибаюсь, нет. Поэтому код, использующий её, будет непереносимым. Если переносимость не нужна, [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620002/10105) есть как раз про этот случай.

Comment: Да, я знаю, просто дополнил, кому-то может быть полезно. Тем более что есть случаи  и методы когда переносимость обеспечивается уже кодом программиста для требуемых платформ. С откатом к переносимой версии

Answer (score 1):

В C++ нет оператора возведения в степень. Оператор ^ в C++ означает побитовый оператор исключающего ИЛИ.

К тому же вывод сообщений, является ли число степенью 2, нужно вынести за пределы цикла.

Можно использовать подход, похожий на ваш, но когда исходное число делится на 2, пока не получится 1 и остаток от деления будет равен 0.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const unsigned int Base = 2;

        unsigned int n;

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) || ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        unsigned int i = 0;
        unsigned int m = n;

        while (  m != 1 && m % Base == 0  )
        {
            ++i;
            m /= Base;
        }

        if ( m == 1 )
        {
            std::cout << n << " is equal to " 
                      << Base << " in power of "
                      << i << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << n << " is not power of "
                      << Base << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может, к примеру, выглядеть следующим образом

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1
1 is equal to 2 in power of 0
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2
2 is equal to 2 in power of 1
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4
4 is equal to 2 in power of 2
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8
8 is equal to 2 in power of 3
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 16
16 is equal to 2 in power of 4
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 32
32 is equal to 2 in power of 5
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3
3 is not power of 2
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4
5 is not power of 2
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7
7 is not power of 2
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9
9 is not power of 2
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Данный подход можно использовать для проверки, является ли число степенью некоторого другого заданного числа, то есть необязательно двойки. Для этого достаточно заменить в программе значение константы `Base` на любое число по вашему усмотрению.

Либо вы можете воспользоваться функцией, представленной в вопросе [Спецификатор noexcept](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633785/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-noexcept)

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int n, k = 1, s = 1;
        cin >> n;
        if (n == 1) cout << "YES";
        for (int a = 1; a *= 2 <= n; a *= 2)//4
        {
            if (2*a == n) cout << "YES";
            s *= 2;
            if (2*a == n) break;
        }
         if (s != n) cout << "NO";
    }
```

Comment: Алгоритм [не выглядит работоспособным](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4686652d6933a14).

Comment: Эта параша работает, и я не знаю как

Comment: Я делал это полтора часа

Comment: В любом случае, в соседнем ответе есть хитрая запись в одну строчку без цикла, которая делает то же самое.